# Quering a Table from a different DB in Derby

Tags: sql, database, derby

I have 2 Derby databases, and i need to sync records from say table T1 in DB1 with T2 in DB2. Both T1 and T2 are virtually the same tables but present in different DBs.

I tried using the syntax "select * from DB1.SCHEMA.T1", but this doesn't seem to work in Derby.

How to go about this.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way to do this. A JDBC connection to Derby is only connected to a single database at a time. It would be a nice feature, but for now I think you should investigate other approaches. For example, read all the data from 1 database into memory, close that connection, open a connection to the other DB, and do the necessary inserts from your in-memory data.

Comment: @Bryan.. Thanks for the update. But is this an issue with Derby only. Because i was able to do this in Oracle where i can query a table from a different DB.

Comment: You can't query a table from a "different DB" in Oracle unless you use a DBLink to do that (e.g. `select * from some_table@remote_database`). What exactly did you do in Oracle?

Comment: Yes.. it was using dblink. Is that possible in Derby as well. If so how..